# How to put a square bracket on ZBarReaderView?

Tags: iphone, ios, zbar-sdk

I am developing a qrcode scanner and I am using ZBarSdk for that. I am able to successfully reading all the qrcode and parsing them into meaningful information. While watching some of the example I found that ZBarReaderViewController can place a image while scanning mimicking the scan area. They are using the cameraOverlay feature for the the same, however I am not finding the same for ZBarReaderView. How can I put an image on the scan surface?

I could have used the ZBarReaderViewController however my app is designed in such a manner that if I use ZBarReaderViewController, I will face issue in modalviewcontroller present so I am badly in need of cameraoverlay with ZBarReaderView. Below is the link where I got to know about the cameraOverlayView feature for ZBarReaderViewController.

[Is it possible to put a square bracket for the focus when the camera appears in the ZBar SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291299/is-it-possible-to-put-a-square-bracket-for-the-focus-when-the-camera-appears-in)

[image: I want my look alike like this]

Answer (score -1):

I made it with the below code, after initializing the ZBarReaderView:

```
UIImage *ivg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];
UIImageView *bh = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, height, width)];
bh.image = ivg;
[self.view addSubview:bh];
```